# What is wrong in this way of using PHP scandir() function?

Tags: php, directory, scandir

I have been writing a simple PHP script for reading all files in a directory and show them but it show Unknown files, my files in images folder just two images but `scandir()` returning to me 4 result that first is "." (point) and second is ".." (double point).
these results are from where?

This is my PHP function :

```
    $carpet_images=scandir('./images');

    print_r($carpet_images);
```

and this is result:

```
Array
(
[0] => .
[1] => ..
[2] => 1562475195-1796949251.jpg
[3] => 5f931b6fdbbdc8bfbd164f4bb08334ec_zzz-1.jpg
)
```

Comment: `.` is the current directoy, `..` is the parent directory

Comment: Did you ever look at the output fron a `dir` or `ls -a`

Comment: In almost every example of scandir there is code to ignore the `.` and `..`  directories

Comment: No, I didn't looked dir or ls -a output in this case because I am using this script in a share host and I have not access to command line

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63081/what-are-and-directories

Comment: _No, I didn't looked dir or ls -a output_ What? Never? On any system? Even Windows??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is the current directory, `..` is the parent directory. You can filter those out like this:

```
$directories = scandir("./images");

$carpet_images = array_filter($directories, function($var) {
    return !in_array($var, ['.', '..']);
});
```